# Adding Line Break on Multi-Select Dropdown in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown, page-break

I have an order tracking sheet I made in Google Sheets. I have an `Items` column with a dropdown populated from an Items List sheet, and I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369296/selecting-multiple-values-from-a-dropdown-list-in-google-spreadsheet) to setup the multi select function, and it works great.

Here's my to [actual code](https://gist.github.com/coinsandsteeldev/4c67dfa5411e8add913273fc5a30f5e7)

The only issue I have is the items are separated by `,` in the cell, but the line breaks are not by item, just based on line length overall, there is too much variation to just adjust the column width. I would like each item to be on their own line within the one cell, essentially having a line break after each item is selected.

Currently I get this:

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item
3, Item 4
```

I would like:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

I found a part in the code where it adds the `,` after each item and I can change the comma to something else, but I don't know how to make a break there.

I tried `\n`, `<br>`, etc. I am assuming I am just putting the break in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/coinsandsteeldev/4c67dfa5411e8add913273fc5a30f5e7#file-multi-select-gs-L26

Change to `var separator = '\n'`