# Selecting multiple items from a drop down on multiple columns using onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use a script to allow for multiple items to be selected from drop down lists in multiple columns.  Here is the script I have used - it works perfectly for one column, but I can figure out how to apply the script to multiple columns.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 10  && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="DASH") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue) <0) {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet to check how it is currently working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369296/selecting-multiple-values-from-a-dropdown-list-in-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Tested the script from the answer and as long as your data validation is "List from a range" it works great.